# Re-painting 1903 Lath and Plaster Walls: Advice on next steps

Tags: painting, lath-and-plaster

I'm working on repainting and decorating an old home I just bought, built in 1903. I've removed the most recent layer of paint and three layers of wallpaper that were put in 20, 50 and ? years ago to get down to the original plaster.

My original plan for what comes next was:

- Use joint compound to fill small holes and even out cracks
- Clean walls with warm water and tsp
- Even out walls with thin skim coat
- Sand everything down
- Prime
- Paint

Does that sound right? Am I going overboard with the full skim coat?

Comment: Whether or not you're going overboard is a personal decision that probably depends on your tolerance for imperfections, i.e. the amount of Fs you give.

Comment: Sanding lead-based paint can be hazardous. Resources here: https://www.epa.gov/lead

Comment: Your question is rather broad, and whether you need a skim coat is unclear without seeing what you see (and somewhat subjective to boot). Please revise to be more specific and ask just one question. Take the [tour] for more tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going about it right. Perhaps clean the walls before the repairs, instead of after filling holes and such. THe drywall mud used does not like getting wet.  The skim coat over the walls may not be needed if the walls are already smooth, free of cracks. Any cracks will need to be taped. Use paper tape, I have found using mesh tape sometimes lets the crack radiate through the surface again, so I stopped using it.

One other suggestion may be to prime the walls first after washing, to solidify the surfaces before repairs, so the sanding done will not remove any of the original plaster as quickly.

Lead based paint should be a concern, but it sounds as if you have the walls down to the plaster with no paint at all.

Comment: We do have the paint and paper down already, had heavy duty masks and gloves on the whole time just in case. Feeling confident with your suggestions, will definitely wash the walls before and tape up cracks before skim.